# Changing volume for one alarm sound only on Android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am working on a life saving medical app and if the user is in a life threatening situation, they need to hear the alert.

When I have a notification to the status bar or have a dialog appear for a critical message to the user, I need to get their attention. If the media volume or ringer volume is low or off, I want to override it for my alert only. I would prefer not to change the settings for the phone, just for my one sound that I want to play.

When I try:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 
    audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING), 0);
```

This correctly sets the volume for my stream but has the side effect of changing the stream volume for everyone else.

Is there a way of setting the volume for one song only?

Answer (score 2):

It could be set back after the song is done.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int current_volume=audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 
    audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING), 0); 
// Play here
audioManager.setStreamVolum(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,current_volume,0);
```